# When NFC is set to HCE, the Android repeatedly shows logs about polling and AID registration

Tags: android, logging, nfc, logcat, hce

I use HCE mode as [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html#HceSecurity) shows, but this seems to generate problems on my device.

When I run the app in my phone, Android repeatedly prints the following messages to the debug log. Is this normal?

```
D/NfcService(2868): NFC-C ON
E/BrcmNfcJni(2868): nfcManager_enableDiscovery: already polling
I/NfcService(2868): applyRouting(), screenState = 3
D/NfcService(2868): NFC-EE ON seID = 244 mNfceeRouteEnabled = true mEeRoutingState = 3
E/BrcmNfcNfa(2868): UICC (0xf4) listening already specified
E/BrcmNfcNfa(2868): UICC (0xf4) listening already specified
D/RegisteredAidCache(2868): Updating default component to: null
D/RegisteredAidCache(2868): Current default: null
D/RegisteredAidCache(2868): No default set, last payment service removed.
D/RegisteredAidCache(2868): Updating default component to: null
D/RegisteredAidCache(2868): generateAidTree component: ComponentInfo{de.grundid.hcedemo/de.grundid.hcedemo.MyHostApduService}
D/RegisteredAidCache(2868): generateAidTree AID: F0010203040506
D/RegisteredAidCache(2868): generateAidTree AID: F0394148148100
D/RegisteredAidCache(2868): updateBlockedList: mode: 0
D/RegisteredAidCache(2868): updateBlockedList: Blocked list has been cleared
D/RegisteredAidCache(2868): resolveAidLocked: resolving AID F0010203040506
D/RegisteredAidCache(2868): resolveAidLocked: next tap component is null
D/RegisteredAidCache(2868): resolveAidLocked: DECISION: cat OTHER AID, routing to (default) ComponentInfo{de.grundid.hcedemo/de.grundid.hcedemo.MyHostApduService}
D/RegisteredAidCache(2868): resolveAidLocked: resolving AID F0394148148100
D/RegisteredAidCache(2868): resolveAidLocked: next tap component is null
D/RegisteredAidCache(2868): resolveAidLocked: DECISION: cat OTHER AID, routing to (default) ComponentInfo{de.grundid.hcedemo/de.grundid.hcedemo.MyHostApduService}
D/AidRoutingManager(2868): Set route for AID: F0010203040506, host: true , current: 0xffffffff
D/AidRoutingManager(2868): Set route for AID: F0394148148100, host: true , current: 0xffffffff
D/AidRoutingManager(2868): reRouteAllAids; sec elem id=0x0 aid=F0010203040506
D/AidRoutingManager(2868): reRouteAllAids; sec elem id=0x0 aid=F0394148148100
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that log output is normal. This should be logged whenever your Android device updates its NFC routing.

The most interesting part for you would be this:

```
D/RegisteredAidCache(<ID>): resolveAidLocked: resolving AID <AID>
[...]
D/RegisteredAidCache(<ID>): resolveAidLocked: DECISION: cat OTHER AID, routing to (default) ComponentInfo{<COMPONENT>}
[...]
D/AidRoutingManager(<ID>): Set route for AID: <AID>, host: true , current: <PREVIOUS_ROUTING>
```

This means that for a certain AID `<AID>`, communication will be routed to the HCE service `<COMPONENT>`. Specifically, `host: true` indicates that the AID was registered to be handled by HCE and not by a secure element.